# Testing for stationarity

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels

I have a question regarding the "correct" **Augmented Dickey–Fuller** (ADF) test with "sm.tsa.stattools.adfuller" in Python / iPython. I'm testing ADF on a time series of temperatures.

According to the [documentation](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.5.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.adfuller.html), the test provides an **autolag** in the args:

*autolag* {‘AIC’, ‘BIC’, ‘t-stat’, None}

- if None, then maxlag lags are used
- if ‘AIC’ or ‘BIC’, then the number
  of lags is chosen to minimize the corresponding information criterium
- ‘t-stat’ based choice of maxlag. Starts with maxlag and drops a lag
  until the t-statistic on the last lag length is significant at the 95
  % level.

Which one is scientifically correct / accepted? (And what does AIC/BIC mean?)

Also, is it possible to calculate an approximate p-value for Z(t), like in some Stata tables? See [Link](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/ts101-150218033520-conversion-gate01/95/time-series-analysis-in-stata-21-638.jpg%3Fcb%3D1424252173)

Comment: [AIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) and [BIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) are model-complexity selection criteria. In practice, model settings are always heuristic, and therefore the library gives you these options. AFAIK, there is no "correct / accepted" answer here.

Comment: Well, the problem is I#m getting completely different results (nobs 40), depending on the model... Is it appropriate to work with first differences?

Comment: It really depends on the data, and it would be easier if you'd somehow provide it.

Comment: Imagine a monthly time series from 2000 to 2015 with each values between 10 and 60